# Difficulty in sarrus method matlab

Tags: matlab

What is the matlab code for determining 3x3 matrix using sarrus method?

Answer (score 1):

You've got your matrix A. Then:

`A(1,1)*A(2,2)*A(3,3) + A(1,2)*A(2,3)*A(3,1) + A(1,3)*A(2,1)*A(3,2) - A(3,1)*A(2,2)*A(1,3) - A(3,2)*A(2,3)*A(1,1) - A(3,3)*A(2,1)*A(1,2)`

is the code to find the determinant of a $3$x$3$ matrix using Sarrus' rule.

Note: I recommend that you do some research before asking a question on this site, because this particular question could be easily solved by reading the Matlab documentation.

Comment: I am not sure the OP is simply asking this. IMHO he asks for solving a linear system of 3 equations with 3 unknowns $AX=B$. Waiting for his/her comments...

Comment: Now that you say it, I'm not sure either @JeanMarie . I'll edit or delete the answer altogether depending on what OP says.